# DataProvidor is not supported by maven-surefire-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I use testNg as my automation, but the issue is when run tests with eclipse, everything goes well, but when I run with mvn command, it seems that maven-surefire-plugin wont pick up test methods with @Test(dataProvider=XXX) and just run beforetest methods. Any one know how to solve this issue?

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testNg.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <!-- <argLine>${surefireargs} -XX:UseSplitVerifier</argLine> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the way you are specifying your tests in pom.xml.  Post more info on how are you invoking your tests from maven for someone to help you out.

Comment: @MojunZhu Please add this to your question. The comments' (non-)formatting isn't too convenient.

Comment: Thanks Gerold, I just added my pom information in the questions, it is the same in the comments. Just deleted my previous comments and update questions content.